# SQL Server group by with inline SQL

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I'm trying to combine the two queries below. Any ideas how.. I can't simply add group by to the first query.

The first one brings back the max date out of the two dates, but the table holds multiple rows for each case. So the second query is to bring back the max date per case.

```
Select ID, CaseNo, 
(SELECT MAX(v) FROM (VALUES (DateOne), (DateTwo)) AS value(v)) as [DateMain]
Into #TMP1
From Table1
```

```
SELECT CaseNo, MAX(DateMain)[DateMain] 
FROM #TMP1 as [DateMain]
GROUP BY DateMain
```

**This does not work:**

```
Select ID, CaseNo, 
(SELECT MAX(v) FROM (VALUES (DateOne), (DateTwo)) AS value(v)) as [DateMain]
Into #TMP1
From Table1
Group by CaseNo
```

Comment: Your "working" code has syntax errors. There is no DateSettled column in #TMP1 and the second query is missing a comma separating the columns. Your third query does not attempt to use or compute a column named DateSettled. So the implication is that your actual query is more complicated. But finding the max value between 2 columns is trivial - did you just go off the deep end and overcomplicate things? A simple case expression can be used to find the later date for a row and that expression can be used within a MAX aggregate. Again - all simple stuff.

Comment: I've edited the Q. Can you give an example of 'A simple case expression can be used to find the later date for a row and that expression can be used within a MAX aggregate'

Answer (score 0):

You have to aggregate DateOne and DateTwo to be used with that GROUP BY clause, the partition may work in your query for this. However, you also have to aggregate the result of the comparison to work with your result set.

```
Select ID, CaseNo, 
MAX((SELECT MAX(v) FROM (VALUES (MAX(DateOne)), (MAX(DateTwo))) AS value(v))) OVER( PARTITION BY ID, CaseNo) as [DateMain],
MAX(DateSettled)
Into #TMP1
From Table1
```

Comment: Remove the `group by`